# Writing dataframe to CSV - Spark 1.6

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to write a pyspark dataframe to CSV. I have Spark 1.6, and I am trying things such as the line: `df.write.format('com.intelli.spark.csv).save('mycsv.csv')` and `df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save(PATH)`.

These always give an error along the lines of `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.intelli.spark.csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org`.

I have tried downloading `spark-cv_2.10-0.1.jar` and using it in the `--jars` argument of `spark-submit`, but that also leads to a similar error. I have also tried `spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0` but it gives server access errors.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way. In spark 1.6, you will have to covert it to rdd and write.

```
def toCSVLine(data):
    return ','.join(str(d) for d in data)

rdd1 = df.rdd.map(toCSVLine)
rdd1.saveAsTextFile('output_dir')
```

Edit-

Try to add this in your spark code after passing
--py-files argument. 
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("/path/to/jar/xxxx.jar")